# Javascript, value=true when clicking inside an iframe.

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick

This is the codes that i've have written, i'm new to javascript so there's probably some  easy mistakes and hopefully someone know how to fix it because at the moment the "alert"  pops up even if you clicked the iframe. Feel free to ask if you want more info about code  or what to know anything:)

```
<script language="javascript">
var value = false;
function openlink()
{
alert('yo');
}
function getIt()
{
if(value == true)
  window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/','_self');

if(value == false)
  alert("...");
}
</script>

<iframe onclick="javascript:value=true;" src="..." scrolling="no" frameborder="0"       style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:350px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true">  </iframe>
```

Comment: This code must be incomplete since both alerts are in functions that are not executed with the current code.

Comment: Events inside the `iframe` won't bubble up to the `iframe` element. If it is not from the same domain, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Can you describe what you're actually trying to accomplish as I've got some hints for you that may push you in the right direction, but I need a little more. If you're ONLY trying to use JavaScript, your first lesson, is to remember what you've learned here, and try using a library like jQuery to do it. This will help you traverse your DOM easier, as well as keeps your JavaScript/jQuery unobtrusive.

Comment: @FelixKling lol, you just said "bubble up" to someone who uses inline javascript on html elements... Just thought that was kinda funny.

Comment: @Relic—do you think inline listeners don't bubble?

Comment: @pimvdb i didn't want to post the whole code but ofc the alert functions are executed.

Comment: @FelixKling but onmouseover works?

Comment: Is this a statement or a question?

Comment: @RobG clearly not what I was getting at, but anyways Oskar still hasn't elaborated on the task he's trying to accomplish. I realize this may be a pet project, but an alert is never a way to deliver information, so you're obviously using that as a catch to see where you are in the code. Elaborate on what you want to accomplish and why you're using an iFrame, and maybe we can help you with a solution to your problem instead of going in circles about inline obtrusive JavaScript.

Comment: @Relic the iframe is essential because it's a like button from facebook. I want people to like before they can click a link, so if they havent clicked the iframe, an alert pop ups and if they have clicked the iframe they can proceed. but if the onlick doesn't, do you  have any suggestion of how it could work?

Comment: The below way lets you keep from having JS inline on your iFrame... infact lets you avoid even parsing the iFrame or referencing it at all.. just use links and js to see if a cookie/browser-storage is set.

Comment: @Relic—I can only take your statement at face value, I'm not sure what you meant. Anyhow, it seems that the OP wants to do something only if the user has previously clicked on a particular iframe. How the listeners are attached is irrelevant, it's where they are attached and their logic that matters.

Comment: @RobG isn't 'where' and 'their logic', part of 'how' ?

Comment: and before you say something silly, I can think of 3 ways at least to implement a click event listener that has different logic with the same set of selectors in different parts of the code, and all are for different reasons...

Comment: The various methods of attaching listeners may change how to get a reference to the related event object, the value of the function's *this* keyword and when the listener is available. But they are general issues and are dealt with based on the method of attachment. As far as the internal processing of the listener, it is identical provided the above issues are dealt with. In any case, events inside an iFrame don't bubble to the iFrame, so the OP's strategy for ensuring users click within the iFrame before other logic is processed is unsuitable.

Comment: unsuitable, or just something you don't know how to fully execute? Because you can parse the elements of an iFrame, and watch them, except for anything in the <head> because those all come in as textNodes for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should never keep someone from browsing your site because some people like me don't have a FaceBook, and therefor can't LIKE your site. This is also really really poor SEO.

So, instead you can do this:

-User enters site first time
   -user clicks a link
   -set pop-up cookie = true & || set browser storage pop-up cookie = true
   -pop-up with request to like the site
   -user likes or doesn't like the pop-up/site
   -close box, forwards user along the link
    
   -User enters with cookie & || browser storage set
   - use link normally

Or, at the end of the day, you could just use the FB API - But again... you don't want them to not be able to continue to use your site if they haven't liked it.
-Get FB UserID
-Check FB API for if UserID has LIKE "myurl.com"

Comment: Thanks, but firts i just want to say that the site is worthless for people without facebook, and second, i don't know how to use cookies. You know any good guides or something that i can learn from?

Comment: well that's okay, but you can't force them to LIKE it, just to use it... that's bad marketting. Either way, avoid using cross-domain stuff when you can, and def avoid parsing into iFrames when you can too just because you'll likely have a <HEAD> element, and that comes back as a string, not nodes... something interesting I've learned.

Comment: As for a cookies guide, it depends on the serverside script you're using, but... StackOverflow is a great resource for all things coding :) If you're not using server-side code for anything right now... well... I'm not sure how you're doing the UGC but if you can get it going, more power too ya to just have templates that fill with social data that's well aggregated.

Comment: Ohhh, and there's a new Cookie Law out too. You have to allow users to Opt-In to recieve cookies, you can't force them. That's another reason you don't wanna force people to have liked your page...